# Actionbar not shown on second activity with webview

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am working on a project in Android Studio. My MainActivity shows the Actionbar. I created a new empty activity named Teachers. It shows the Actionbar when it's empty. I then created a webview. But when I input this webview code on Teachers activity, the Actionbar is not shown in the app (even though the webview works properly).

```
package com.codepade.shohel.eee7brur;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    public class Teachers extends Activity {

        private WebView webView;
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_teachers);
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.teachersweb);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/teachers/index.html");
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                switch(keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if(webView.canGoBack() == true){
                            webView.goBack();
                        }else{
                            finish();
                        }
                        return true;
                }

            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: post your teachers.xml please.. `activity_teachers.xml`

Comment: check your manifest file in Teachers activity pass in noActionbar in theam.

Comment: post the contents of `activity_teachers.xml` and `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

in your Activity you can try `getActionBar().show();`